# Bootstrap modal form closing before validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I used the example here to build my form: http://bootply.com/60244

My javascript doesn't appear to be invoked and so the form closes as soon as I click on "Save Changes". Any thoughts would be appreciated

**Here is my code**

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal hide fade" id="mailerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h3_pink id="myModalLabel">Request a Mailer Bag</h3_pink>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3_pink> </h3>
            <form method="post" id="FormMailer" action="soon2.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="FormMailer" value="1">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="contact_fname" id="contact_fname" style="width:90%"><span class="hide help-inline">This is required</span></td>
                        <td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" name="contact_lname" id="contact_lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="width:90%"><span class="hide help-inline">This is required</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Email Address</td><td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" placeholder="Email Address" style="width:90%"><span class="hide help-inline">This is required</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Street1</td><td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="contact_street1" name="contact_street1" placeholder="Street" style="width:90%"><span class="hide help-inline">This is required</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Street2</td><td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="contact_street2" name="contact_street2" placeholder="Street" style="width:90%"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>City</td><td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="contact_city" name="contact_city" placeholder="City" style="width:90%"><span class="hide help-inline">This is required</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Zip</td><td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" style="width:90%"><span class="hide help-inline">This is required</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Message</td><td colspan="3"><textarea id="contact_message" name="contact_message" style="width:90%"></textarea></td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="FormMailerSubmit">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    <!-- Modal Ends -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/soon/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="soon/styles/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="soon/styles/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" media="screen"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="soon/styles/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="soon/styles/style_responsive.css"/>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#FormMailerSubmit').click(function(){
            if ($('#contact_fname').val()==="") {
                  // invalid
                  $('#contact_fname').next('.help-inline').show();
                  return false;
                }
                else {
                  // $('#FormMailer').submit();

                  return true;
                }
            });
        });           
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its closing due to the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute on the button. Remove that and it won't close. If you need to close it in your JS you can use `modal.modal('hide');`

Comment: The example code that I linked above shows the data-dismiss="modal" in the save changes button code sample ... but just to be on the safe side, I removed the data-dismiss="modal" and it still closes. I may have a conflict in my js files which is causing none of my embedded js to be executed at all

Comment: I actually think I had this problem before with 2 buttons in a modal. How about trying an anchor tag for the save changes button instead, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first things first

- specify the type in all buttons - the default type should be a 
  `submit` button, not a normal button.
- you might want to do the validation in the modal `hide` event. If the
  data is not valid, return `false` from the event handler, and it
  won't close. This just leaves you the minor problem of identifying
  whether the event came from a close/cancel button or the intended
  submit button....